# Does attr_accessible applied to user-related properties prevent user-data forgery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

I was looking at an authentication system which had this code:

```
  # prevents a user from submitting a crafted form that bypasses activation
  # anything else you want your user to change should be added here.
  attr_accessible :login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name
```

I don't understand why attr_accessible is applied to these properties.

Is the comment correct that this prevents a user from forging a form to manipulate user data? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr_accessible` indicates which properties can be accessed via mass-assignment.  If you had an action on your controller that did mass-assignment and you didn't use this method, the user could alter data that you didn't intend to let them alter.

In this case, a user could bypass activation by adding a parameter to the form POST for the boolean `activated` field, thus creating a user without verifying that they have a legitimate email address.  (Assuming it's called `activated`.)  This would be a big problem if your system has the potential for things like comment spam.

[API documentation for `attr_accessible`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002281)

Answer (score 0):

What `attr_accessible` is really doing is making the *other* attributes protected. It's the opposite of the `attr_protected` macro. Rails will generate `thing=` methods automatically, so `attr_protected` is harder to use than the whitelist version, `attr_accessible`.

The idea is to protect sensitive fields from users manipulating URLs and forms.

Comment: Yeah, it'd be much clearer with the `attr_protected` method, but whitelists are always a better idea than blacklists.